# Command Prompt opens with every installation on my laptop, how to fix?

Tags: command-line

When I do an installation or open some programs, Command Prompt shows up as well.

During installations, it simply displays where every installation file is copied and other details of installation. And when I open some programs, `cmd` runs in background. If I close `cmd`, the software also closes.

How can I remove this? I think it's not a virus.

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear. Please explain what your problem is with more details.

Comment: Should be clear now, looks like a virus to me...

Comment: It ain't clear.

Comment: I guess you are using Windows... but which one of them? would be nice to know...

Answer (score 0):

- As TomWij said it Looks like a Virus
- Download Startup-Manager (freeware). Remove suspicious files from Windows - Start-up (please be cautious otherwise you might disable windows and other 3rd party softwares from starting up along with windows)
- Make sure you do a virus scan after updating your virus definitions.

Comment: no, its not a virus, it simply displays in cmd where every installation file is copied and other details of installation

Comment: Why didn't you say this is in the question. If it showed for one  or two software then it must be a batch file of the installation program. If it is showing for each and every program installation then let me google

Answer (score 0):

Virus for sure. Windows do not need to open cmd every time You install something.
First run Combofix, then unplug hdd from machine plug (ex. via usb bay) to other computer and make complete offline antivirus scan of suspicious drive.